# Mini player on browser and remains static on the bottom right corner

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, youtube, jwplayer, video.js

As I am using a browser and playing some movies or content on the browser. I got a idea why not play a static player in the browser which plays **youtube video** or any other website videos which is supporting this option.

1. player not dependent on web page a static page.
2. support drag and drop to any place on the browser.
3. even when we click on other pages the static page should play and remain constant.
4. try to support all the players which are running on the browser.

and please this is just an opinion from my side.
If there is any browser or software supporting this feature let me know here
**Advance thanks**

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this 2 extension for chrome browser

1. Floating Player
2. Picture in picture for your browser

It is a small achievement.

[image]